# 'VarToStr' in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Im trying to migrate an old project from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE.
When i try to compile the project now i get this error:

```
[DCC Error] *.pas(352): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'VarToStr'
```

about this line:

```
PropValue := VarToStr(GetPropValue(Component, PropInfo^.Name));
```

It works fine in Delphi 5, and as far as i have found out VarToStr is also supported in XE ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to call VarToStr, you can just assign to the string as so:

```
PropValue := GetPropValue(Component, PropInfo^.Name);
```

Comment: +1 you're right, however it doesn't hurt to keep the code as it is until he is familiar with the app. functionality and stuff. but you made a very good point there!!

Comment: Yes i will keep it so until it all compiles and then start to make changes, but i will wright it down as a point to alter, thanks.

Comment: @Roise I'm reasonably confident that my code snippet above will compile in Delphi 5 too, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @all I'm 99.999% sure that David's H. snippet will compile on Delphi 5 without any issue!

Comment: You have to be careful with some versions of Delphi. If the variant is **Null** then the implicit conversion will fail with `EVariantError` "Invalid variant type conversion". That's the reason we have an entire library of `VarToXxx` to properly handle nulls. i know newer versions of Delphi updated the `VarToXxx` to handle variant type conversions; i don't know if implicit conversions still fail though.

Answer (score 17):

Add *Variants*(and maybe TypInfo aswell...) to **uses** clause.